# RegExp multipart phrase

Tags: regex, replace

I have such text (not RegEx, but simple text i my text file) phrase:  `\abc{xyz}{uvw}`, and I'd like to change it to: `xyz : uvw`. `xyz` and `uvw` can be various, but `\abc{}{}` is constant.

Is there any way to replace this first phrase, to this second? I have it 380 times in my file, and changing it manually will take me an hour. I have also other similar phrases with other names than `abc`.

If I'd have a RegEx to replace it would be a big advantage for me. Could you help me with writing this `RegExp`?

PS. If you'd like to know, this phrases are LaTeX user defined commands.

Type of RegEx doesn't matter. I just need to correct the text (it's a lecture of my professor of Math). I need to correct it, but I gave no lots of time.

Comment: Write the constant part as is, use `.*?` or `[^}]*` to match the varying parts, group that into `(capturing groups)`, refer to those two capturing groups in your replacement pattern.

Comment: As per the [tag:regex] tag description, you need to explain what tools you are trying to use, or have at your disposal. Please [edit] your question, ideally to also reveal what you have already searched for, what you found, what you have tried, and how it failed.

Comment: You need to share the regex(es) you have tried to achieve the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replies. I have no idea how to achieve this task. I'm a programmer but I don't know RegEx as good, as I would be able to do it. I can write simple regex, but here i have two groups, and I don't know how give it a goal. ie. i have such line ```\newline\newline$\FA{\bel{K, L}{\Class}}(\rown{K = L}{\FA{x}(\rown{\bel{x}{K}}{\bel{x}{L}})})$```. t has many ```\bel``` inside. I need to get the every ```\bel``` as single

Comment: The regex for such job is not really complex, but you have to tell what language/tool you are using.

Comment: It doen't matter. It will not be a program. I just need to correct the text of lecture

Comment: Regexes don't replace, tools using regex do.

Comment: To be understood. I need only the code of RegEx in any gender. I can open online editor, ie. https://regexr.com/ and put it there

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/QrjmYR/1) what you need? I just implemented my first comment, although I'm getting less and less sure I understand your need.

Comment: Sorry. Ok, lets say i'll do it in PHP RegEx. Could you tell me the code of RegEx? :)

Comment: @Aaron 57 steps seems a lot for such a short string.

Comment: @MartinZeitler feel free to provide your optimized alternative.

Comment: Guys, sorry for interuption of this interesting dialog. I just please you, to post the RegEx (PHP ie.). If you would like to take some cash for it, I can pay. I have not much time...

Comment: @mpaw seriously dude I provided a comment explaining what to do then a regex101 link where I did it showing it worked, I don't know what else I can do here. Unless my solution is not what you're expecting, then please tell me how/what's wrong with it.

Comment: OH, I'm so sorry,, i haven't spotted this link. Thank you

Comment: @Aaron: Give it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following :

- match `\\abc{([^}]*)}{([^}]*)}`
- replace by `\1 : \2`

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/QrjmYR/1).

`[^}]*` matches every character but `}`, it is used to match the content of the brackets without risk of overflowing.

Aside from that we escape the `\` to match its literal character, group the content of two brackets in their own capturing group to which we refer in the replacement pattern.